# netsuite managing portlets in customers dashboard and home dashoard

Tags: netsuite

In Netsuite, how to manage the viewed portlets in customers dashboard and home dashoard.

In Admin role, How can I handle which portlet should be visible in customers dashboard and home dashoard and where can I setup(add/remove) the particular portlets to come in all customers dashboards without the need to personalize dashboard by each customer?

Thanks in Adance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setup which portlets appear in the customer dashboard by publishing your dashboard for particular roles. Once you have setup your dashboard,

- go to the Setting portlet in your Home tab.
- Click on "Publish Dashboard".
- Name the dashboard and select which Roles this would apply to, along with the relevant tabs.